# Choose the number of elements of a python list by grouping some of these data contents

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am doing an automatic text translator on manga. I translate the detected sentence but I need to have as many elements in the list (because the number of words differs according to the language).

Ex:

```
['yeaH,', 'eur', 'YOu', 'Have', 'KNACK', 'FOR', 'MAKING', 'PEOPLE', 'FEEL', 'COMFORTABLE', '‘AROUND', 'YOU,']

['Ouais EUR', 'Vous', 'avez Knack', 'pour', 'faire sentir', 'que', 'les gens', 'se', 'sentent à', "l'aise", '"autour de', 'toi,']
```

That is, there is the same number of elements in the list with grouped words. But I have no idea how to do it. (note I need the same number of elements because I replace each detected word by a word in the translated sentence, so if the sentence is bigger, some elements are skipped.

The best thing would be to be able to choose the number of elements in the list with split like this

```
text_original=['yeaH,', 'eur', 'YOu', 'Have', 'KNACK', 'FOR', 'MAKING', 'PEOPLE', 'FEEL', 'COMFORTABLE', '‘AROUND', 'YOU,']
trans=trans.split(len(text_original))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't get the question right. Could you please explain it more detailed, for example what are the two lists in the first code element? And splitting by length won't work that way in Python, you have to specify the delimiter, not a number (`my_test.split('_')`).

Comment: the two lists contain 1 the basic text detected by tessanter and the other the translation and it's true I misused the split but it's to give an idea of what to do (break my sentence into 5 elements containing each word). What I want is to have a list of 5 elements that contain the sentence and separated by words^^